# How can I get guake to start?

Tags: command-line, guake

When I try to start `guake` it fails and I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/guake", line 1422, in <module>
    if not main():
  File "/usr/bin/guake", line 1365, in main
    instance = Guake()
  File "/usr/bin/guake", line 653, in __init__
    notification.show()
  glib.GError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files
```

I can use `guake-prefs` to alter the settings back to their defaults, but `guake` still fails to load. Even if I reinstall or reboot, it still doesn't run.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This often happens because your desktop environment's notification daemon cannot be started or is unavailable, as noted [at the official site](http://guake.org/ticket/416). It is not a `guake` bug because a notification program is one of guake's dependencies and should be installed with the program, or should be running in the background anyway. Therefore it is legitimate to speak of ways of addressing this problem, which is specific to the user's desktop environment, rather than being a deficiency in `guake` itself.

This error message unfortunately means `guake` fails to load, but there is a way to get around it, as opening the preferences with `guake-prefs` and unchecking 'enable popup notifications at startup' should enable `guake` to load. If this is unsuccessful you can make sure you have the notify daemon installed for your desktop environment (and `python-notify`), and that the notification daemon is running. Notification daemons are usually automatically started at login for most desktops such as Xfce, which uses `xfce4-notifyd`.

Lastly, if these solutions are unsuccessful, you can also try this [patch at the official site](http://guake.org/attachment/ticket/416/ignore_notify_error.patch), and patch the source code and compile it, just as I did (for another guake feature) in my answer here:

- [How to change Guake cursor from block to I-Beam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234626/how-to-change-guake-cursor-from-block-to-i-beam/234659#234659)

That answer has all the general information about how to patch `guake` and compile it, if the other options do not solve the problem.

(As the op noted, what worked for him this time was was to reinstall `python-notify`, which was one of the dependencies I mentioned in the answer. The other approaches may well be useful when that particular solution is unsuccessful.)

Comment: Many Thanks. Problem Solved. sudo apt-get remove python-notify && sudo apt-get install python-notify solved the problem. Is there any way to +rep you or is that done by the admins when they see a problem is solved? Also I was wondering if you can help me with one more problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/267965/trying-to-get-opengl-2-shaders-to-work-glxinfo-says-i-have-4-20-installed One of the reasons I went the kde route is now that I am doing more work and gaming a lot less, used linux before but xfce & mint due to low hardware. Would be nice kde effects; then again i can just youtube it.

Comment: @user140393 That's good you got it sorted out. In response to your question: to show that a question has been solved the question poser clicks a green tick near the answer to accept that answer.