# guake not working

Tags: python, guake

I have seen other answers to this question, but I needed to post this again because there is no response from the maintainers on guake on this issue. i saw the possible answers in [this ask ubuntu answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268145/how-can-i-get-guake-to-start/269178#269178), but it did not apply to me. I tried both `sudo apt-get remove --purge python-notify` and then `sudo apt-get install python-notify`, and that did not change the situation at all, guake still will not start and i still get the same error message everyone else sees:

```
$ guake
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/guake", line 1429, in <module>
    if not main():
  File "/usr/bin/guake", line 1373, in main
    instance = Guake()
  File "/usr/bin/guake", line 660, in __init__
    notification.show()
glib.GError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files
```

The answers in the previously referenced Ask Ubuntu answer no longer apply - there is no more patch to be found on the "official" guake.org site, as that site lost its domain on 20th October, 2014 and has not been updated nor is there a new site. There is no response either regarding that from the official maintainers at [the github repository for guake](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/399). any other suggestions on making this work, or should i just uninstall?

Also, if the software, and its patches and its "official" site are not going to be maintained, I feel it should be removed from the Ubuntu Software Center - it is deceiving to install something only to have it not work and no other solution available.

please advise.

Comment: If the project is indeed dead, file a bug at the Launchpad page of guake. It will be removed from future releases of Ubuntu (but not from current releases). What version of Ubuntu are you using, btw? Guake works fine on 14.04.

Comment: i'm also on ubuntu linux 14.04 LTS with unity. if it is working on your system, have you ever seen this error? if so, how did you get around it? also, could you give me the url link for filing a bug at the Launchpad page for quake? never been there. thank you for the response. still would prefer to make it work.

Comment: The bug report page for guake would be https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quake/+filebug, and did you try re-installing `notify-osd`? `guake` depends on `notification-daemon`, which is provided by `notify-osd` for Unity.

Comment: that did it @muru! i tried first `sudo apt-get remove --purge notify-osd` in case i needed to remove it first for the re-install, but it turned out it was never installed in the first place! so i did `sudo apt-get install notify-osd` - and right after that, it worked perfectly! thank you!

Comment: i'll also make mention of this as a suggestion issue in their  [guake GitHub repository](https://github.com/Guake/guake/ "The GitHub repository for Guake.").

Comment: i also finally got responses there on [the issue i filed there](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/399 "The issue faddah filed in the Guake GitHub repository -  guake.org domain expired oct. 20 2014 - please update README.md, renew and/or get new site? #399") about updating their guake.org domain or their README.md or both. one last thing @muru - would you please copy & paste your answer of installing `notify-osd` into the answer field and post that on this thread and i'll mark it as best answer? thank you, again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`guake` depends on `notification-daemon`:

```
$ apt-cache depends guake
guake
...
 Depends: notification-daemon
  dunst
  mate-notification-daemon
  notify-osd
  plasma-widgets-workspace
  xfce4-notifyd
```

It is a hard dependency, so one of those packages **must** be installed. You could try reinstalling `notify-osd`, which is the usual package for Unity, or install it if it isn't present. See if another of those packages is installed and mention it in any bugs you file, since it doesn't seem to work for guake.

Comment: thanx @muru - voted it best answer. also filed this as [issue #400 at the guake GitHub repo](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/400 "The issue in the Guake GitHub Repository -  suggestion - remind ubuntu linux users to make sure notify-osd is installed. #400"). _(i would have posted this comment earlier but askubuntu.com went into read-only mode while on maintenance shortly after you posted the answer.)_

Comment: @faddah so, was any of the other packages (`dunst`, `mate-notification-daemon`, etc.) installed?

Comment: i did do the whole `sudo apt-get build-dep guake` before installing it, so i assume yes. and as i said, since doing your `sudo apt-get install notify-osd` guake is now running a-ok. so i don't know how to answer your question further?

Comment: @faddah what I think is perhaps `dunst` or `mate-notification-daemon` or another alternative got installed, and `guake` didn't work with them. So it might worthwhile filing a bug with the Guake team that they should test with some of these alternatives.